I need to identify this component - flat, grey, 4 terminals, 8.9 x 5.6 x 2.5mm
I need to identify the component in the picture. In the circuit it is between the GND that arrives at the PCB and the GND that goes to the components, while the other side is between the VCC that arrives at the circuit and the VCC that goes to the components. I imagine that the left and right sides are independent. I assume it is a common mode inductor. It has 2uH of inductance and 0.07 ohms. Its dimensions are 8.9 x 5.6 x 2.5mm. The component doesn't work like a diode.



(After the additional information added by the OP, I have reopened the question. If there are specific details still needed, which would cause people to VTC, please state those in a comment, otherwise the OP can't know what further details to provide.)

That is a 2-line SMD ferrite bead. Used for filtering. Having the two lines side-by-side like that provides some common-mode rejection as well, though not as thoroughly as a common mode choke (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choke_(electronics)) would.
